# change data return by params function in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have this code here:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button @click="changeData(text)">click me !</button>
        <p>{{ text }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                text: 'lorem'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeData(param){
                this.param = 'lorem 1'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I wanna click button then change "text" variable by param in function changeData

Comment: changeData("text") => this["text"] => strong. But: changeData("object.name") => this["object.name"] => wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `text` attribute, then you have to change the `text` attribute, not the `param` attribute.

You seem to think that since you're calling `changeData(text)` that `param`'s value is `text` (correct) and `this.param` is replaced by `this.text` (wrong).

What you're doing currently is changing the `param` attribute to have the value `'lorem 1'`.

If you want the `changeData` function to replace the value of `text`, then you have to change the code inside to `this.text = <new value>`, replacing `<new value>` with either a string literal or a parameter of your function.

If you want the `changeData` function to replace the value of an indicated parameter to `'lorem 1'`, then you need to use `this[param] = 'lorem 1'` instead.

Comment: I tried the way you said earlier. but in a case like this it won't be true anymore: changeData("object.name") => this["object.name"] => wrong

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change the value text variable then value that you are passing 'parm' as a value  in the function should be allocated to text(local variable).
Example:

```
   <template>
        <div>
            <button @click="changeData('NewValue')">click me !</button>
            <p>{{ text }}</p>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            data () {
                return {
                    text: 'lorem'
                }
            },
            methods: {
                changeData(param){
                    this.text=param
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```